# What does "st" parameter mean in Linux "top" utility?

Tags: linux

I'm profiling CPU usage of my server with "top" utility.
One of CPU parameters is marked as "st", now it displays "10.0%st"
What does st mean?
Do you know where can I find info what other params meanlin?

Comment: This belongs on serverfault.com not on stackoverflow.com

Comment: superuser is the right place for this i think. Why are so many bash/top/awk questions put on serverfault? I thought serverfault is just for network? i would love to have shell questions appear on both serverfault and superuser.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

st stands for Stealth Time: the cpu time spent in involuntary wait.

Comment: From the top man: Steal Time - The  amount  of CPU 'stolen' from this virtual machine by the hypervisor for other tasks (such as running another virtual machine).